# Composer update issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, compose-update

I want to upgrade Magento from Magento 2.2.8 to Magento 2.3.3, I have updated Magento's `composer.json` using following command :

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update

Composer json updated successfully, but when I tried to update composer json using `composer update` command then it's return following error.

```
Problem 1
        - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1].
        - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^3.2.1 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[3.2.1].
        - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 3.2.1
        - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.3].
```

What I need to do for solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you change the php version ??

Comment: Hope this helps you http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/upgrade-magento-version-2-2-x-2-3-0/

Comment: Hello @MohitPatel, My current PHP version is 7.1

Comment: Hello @YashPatadia, I have already tried all steps, but when I update composer then it's return above error.

Comment: i think update the php version 7.2

Comment: @MohitPatel I have also tried with updated PHP 7.2, but that time also it's return above error.

Comment: https://github.com/oroinc/crm/issues/116 refer this links

And :- composer require zendframework/zend-stdlib 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command first and after that run Magento upgrade command.

```
composer require zendframework/zend-stdlib
```